# Теги для кнопок objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ctags

Имеется *scrollView*. На ней расположено 1000 кнопок.

Как присвоить каждой кнопке тег с ее индексом?

Пример кода:

```
CGFloat x=0;
CGFloat y=0;


for (int i=0; i < 250; i++) {

    for (int k=0; k< 4; k++) {

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 20, 20);
        [self.mainScroll addSubview: button];
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        x = x+20;        
    }

    x = 0;
    y = y+20;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGFloat x=0;
CGFloat y=0;

for (int i=0; i < 250; i++) {

for (int k=0; k< 4; k++) {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 20, 20);
    [self.mainScroll addSubview: button];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    x = x+20;   

    button.tag = i*4 + k;     
}

x = 0;
y = y+20;

}
```

Comment: спасибо! теперь нужно вывести тег каждой кнопки на нее через setTitle. подскажете? –

Comment: [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", button.tag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: Теперь стоит задача сделать переход на другой вьюконтроллер нажатием любой из этих кнопок. Подскажешь?

Comment: Владимир, это ты можешь найти в любом туториале, или как это называется правильно на русском, базисные вещи, присваиваешь кнопке target и action, и в этом методе создаешь новый контроллер и переход на него и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGFloat x=0;
CGFloat y=0;

int counter = 0;

for (int i=0; i < 250; i++) {

for (int k=0; k< 4; k++) {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 20, 20);
    [self.mainScroll addSubview: button];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    x = x+20;   

    button.tag = counter++;     
}

x = 0;
y = y+20;

}
```